# Should I migrate to Redshift?

Tags: postgresql, nosql, bigdata, amazon-redshift

I'm currently struggling querying be chunk of data that is stored in partitioned table (partition per date)

the data looks like that:

```
date, product_id, orders
2019-11-01, 1, 100
2019-11-01, 2, 200
2019-11-02, 1, 300
```

I have hundreds of date-partitions and millions of rows per date.

Now, if I want to query, for instance,  total orders for product id 1 and 2 for period of 2 weeks, and group by date (to show in a graph per date), the db has to go to 2 weeks of partitions and fetch the data for them.

That process might be taking a long time when the number of products is big or the time frame required is long.

I have read that AWS Redshift is suitable for this kind of tasks. I'm considering shifting my partitioned tables (aggregated analytics per date) to that technology but I wonder if that's really what I should do to make those queries to run much faster.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As per your use case Redshift is really a good choice for you.
To gain the best performance out of Redshift, it is very important to set proper distribution and sort key. In your case "date" column should be distribution key and "productid" should be sort key. Another important note, Do not encode "date" and "productid" column. 
You should get better performance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are struggling with traditional SQL databases, then Amazon Redshift is certainly an option. It can handle tables with billions of rows.

This would involve loading the data from Amazon S3 into Redshift.  This will allow Redshift to optimize the way that the data is stored, making it much faster for querying.

Alternatively, you could consider using **Amazon Athena**, which can query the data directly from Amazon S3. It understands data that is partitioned into separate directories (eg based on date).

Comment: Cons of Athena:
There are limitations on query times, concurrent queries, and Amazon S3 buckets. You need to contact AWS if you want to increase the limits.
There is no support for user-defined functions (UDFs) in Amazon Athena.

Comment: [Amazon Athena Adds support for User Defined Functions (UDF)](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-athena-adds-support-for-user-defined-functions-udf/)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?
Are you using native partioning or inheritance partitioning `trigger-based`?

> Latest version of postgresql improved partitioning management.

Comment: I'm using postgresql 10.7. not sure what does native partitioning means but I'm using the following command to create daily partition: 

create table [partitioned_table] (check  date >= [date_start] and date < [date_end] )) inherits [parent_table];

I know that postgressql  (from version 10.x) supports another form of partitions in a way that I don't have to create partition but it does that automatically. Is that what you mean @Thomas ?

Comment: So, you're using partitioning through inheritance.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) is an overview of declarative partitioning.

Then, I share with you 2 blog post regarding partitioning improvement since PG 10:

* [PG 11](https://pgdash.io/blog/partition-postgres-11.html)
* [PG 12](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/partitioning-enhancements-in-postgresql-12/)

Answer (score 0):

Considering your case **Amazon Redshift** can be a good choice, so does **Amazon Athena**. But it is also important to consider your application framework. Are you opt moving to Amazon only for Database or you have other Amazon services in the list too?

Also before making the decision please check the cost of Redshift.